# How to setup site with second specialised domain name with same content

Tags: seo, google, google-search

I got a website: `company-name-counselling.co.uk`

I have set up all 4 versions of the domain to redirect to `https://www.company-name-counselling.co.uk`.

I have also bought the domains `nearby-town-counselling.co.uk` and `other-town-counselling.co.uk`

I want this site to appear in Google when people search for `counselling in nearby town`.

I will update the title of the home page to include `nearby-town` when accessed on this domain but the content will mostly stay the same.

Will I benefit from having a specific domain for `nearby-town` or will the duplicate content penalise me?

Comment: Adding more domain names never works. As well, duplicate content does not work. You can simply add schema mark-up and locations as a single page as a landing page for search. There maybe other ways of achieving your goals. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is what Google calls [doorway pages](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721311?hl=en).  Having doorway pages can get your entire site (including your original domain) penalized and removed from the search results.  Google doesn't like it when you copy pages, change a few keywords (like the location), and try to rank for all of them.

Using multiple domains is not a good ranking strategy.   These days it is easier to get good rankings with pages on a single domain rather than using keyword-rich alternate domains.  Google stopped ranking keyword rich domains a while ago and now seems to actively demote domains from ranking for non-branded keywords in the domain.

If you want to have your business rank for multiple cities see the tips at [How can I optimize a business site to rank well in local search for multiple cities?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24076/how-can-i-optimize-a-business-site-to-rank-well-in-local-search-for-multiple-cit)